# Multiprocessing fails in python 3x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I  normally work in python 2.7 but I decided to upgrade to python 3.7. and since I made this upgrade, I am having problems with the multiprocessing module. Every time I run the  `Pool` function I retrieve  an error message. For replicability purposes I post here a small example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(x):
    return x**2

pool = mp.Pool(4)
results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

I import the module with no problems and define the `square` function. However, when I try to create the `Pool` by running `pool=mp.Pool(4)`, I get this error message:

[image]

That is repeated over and over again until I stop the Python console.

I am working in a Windows10 PC running Python Miniconda3 (Python 3.7.3)

**EDIT1**

Based on the comments I considered the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def square(x):
    return x**2
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(4)
    results=pool.map(square,range(1,20))
```

Which retrieves the same error as before.

Comment: On Windows you need an `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement to protect the main module as shown and discussed in the section titled "Safe importing of main module" in the `multiprocssing` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)

Comment: Adding an `if __name__ == '__main__'` statement produced also the error message

Comment: Did you put it right before the `pool = mp.Pool(4)` statement (and indent all the lines following it)? It's hard to know precisely because you haven't posted the code that matches what's in the traceback shown...

Comment: Yes, I did as you say, indenting the lines etc. I still get the same error message. In the end my problem is that my parallelized code worked just fine under python 2.7 and now under python 3.7 it is failing.

Comment: That may be the case, but regardless of what version of Python you're using, you need put in the `if __name__ ==  '__main__':`, esp on Windows.

Comment: Yeah but even with the `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement (as indicated in the EDIT1) I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty much clearly mentioned in your traceback that you're having an error at the moment you're trying to open non-existing file with filename `D:\\documents...\\<input>`

You should debug `fname` variable inside of `_get_code_from_file()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not quite an expert on python programming, could you clarify what do you mean with  "debug `fname` variable inside of `_get_code_from_file()` function?

Comment: It looks like you've got wrong filename variable which breaks your code at the moment you're trying to open an unexisting file.

Use some `print()`s or possibly pdb/ipdb debugger to understand where broken value came from.